# WCF nettcp Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

Strange one here.  I have a complex object in a class meaning a class within a class that is being passed to a nettcp WCF service.  All works well when running as localhost.  I can discover the service through VS, I can bind to it, and call the method and receive back my complex object with no problems.  As soon as I move the service to another machine, only the other method calls that return simple objects (classes with strings, booleans, etc).  The method with the complex class does not work.

Too, once I put the service on the remote machine, then go back into VS to bind to it, I get the "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved..." message.  I copied all of the configuration over for service.  Again, all other methods work except for the complex class method, and the fact that it will not bind to the remote service in VS.

Here is the class that will not work:

```
[DataContract]
public class SystemStatus
{
    private XmlDocument statusXml = null;
    private bool callSuccess = false;
    private SystemModule sysMod = null;

    [DataMember]
    public XmlDocument StatusXml
    {
        get { return statusXml; }
        set { statusXml = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public bool CallSuccess
    {
        get { return callSuccess; }
        set { callSuccess = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public SystemModule SysMode
    {
        get { return sysMod; }
        set { sysMod = value; }
    }
}
```

In the above class, the property that broke everything is the "SystemModule" class at the bottom.  If I remove that, the method will work on the remote service, and I can bind to the remote service.

Here is the SystemModule class:

```
[DataContract]
public class SystemModule
{
    private string sysName = "";
    private int sysId = 0;
    [DataMember]
    public string SysName
    {
        get { return sysName; }
        set { sysName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int SysId
    {
        get { return sysId; }
        set { sysId = value; }
    }
}
```

This seems to be a simple fix, all the classes should be serializable.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Is your class in another assembly?

Comment: Yes.  But again, it works locally.  Would that make a difference being remote?  Also, I have datacontract and datamember declared on public properties.  Also, forgot to mention, I have two or three other classes in the other assembly.  Those pass across just fine.  Just the one with class within class is not.